# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "string"' trying to call object literal

Tags: javascript, typescript, object-literal

Well, I am trying to do a dynamic method depending of the let terrain (string) that you will see in the code located at the bottom of this post, so I can create new Terrains only adding them on TERR_CREATE and TERRAINS_CREATE. The code is

```
export class Plains {
    static create(position: string) {
        return 0;
    }
}

export class Mountain {
    static create(position: string) {
        return 0;
    }
}
export interface TERR_CREATE {
     Plains: typeof Plains;
     Mountains: typeof Mountain;
}

export const TERRAINS_CREATE : TERR_CREATE = {
    Plains : Plains,
    Mountains: Mountain,
}
```

The value in the object literal is the class of every terrain (class Plains extends Terrain) for example, and their have a create method.

The problem is when I am trying to select and create a specific terrain. Here is the code:

```
let newPosition = "12";
let terrain = "Plains";
let sel : (keyof TERR_CREATE) = terrain;
TERRAINS_CREATE[sel].create(newPosition);
```

When I run that code I get this error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Plains" | "Mountains"'.

What can I do?

Comment: Now it works, I just need to add `[sel: string]: any;` inside TERR_CREATE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>That code doesn't compile for me (you should generally post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get the best help).</strike> Edit: thanks for updating your code.

I'd say your problem is that `terrain` widens to `string` because you are using `let` to declare it.  Since variables declared via `let` can change their value, usually you wouldn't say `let terrain = "Plains"` unless you plan to *change* the value of `terrain` later.  So the compiler infers that `terrain` is `string`.  If you don't like this inference, you can tell the compiler it is `keyof TERR_CREATE` like this:

```
let terrain: keyof TERR_CREATE = "Plains";
```

[See it in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Plains%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20create%28position%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Mountain%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20create%28position%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20TERR_CREATE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Plains%3A%20typeof%20Plains%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Mountains%3A%20typeof%20Mountain%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20TERRAINS_CREATE%3A%20TERR_CREATE%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Plains%3A%20Plains%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Mountains%3A%20Mountain%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newPosition%20%3D%20%2212%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20terrain%3A%20keyof%20TERR_CREATE%20%3D%20%22Plains%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20sel%3A%20%28keyof%20TERR_CREATE%29%20%3D%20terrain%3B%0D%0ATERRAINS_CREATE%5Bsel%5D.create%28newPosition%29%3B)

And then the rest should work.  Or, if you never want to change the value of `terrain`, you can use a `const` declaration, which TypeScript will infer to be the narrowest type (a string literal in this case):

```
const terrain = "Plains"; // inferred as string literal "Plains"
```

[See it in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Plains%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20create%28position%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Mountain%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20create%28position%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20TERR_CREATE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Plains%3A%20typeof%20Plains%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Mountains%3A%20typeof%20Mountain%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20TERRAINS_CREATE%3A%20TERR_CREATE%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Plains%3A%20Plains%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Mountains%3A%20Mountain%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newPosition%20%3D%20%2212%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20terrain%20%3D%20%22Plains%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20sel%3A%20%28keyof%20TERR_CREATE%29%20%3D%20terrain%3B%0D%0ATERRAINS_CREATE%5Bsel%5D.create%28newPosition%29%3B)

and the rest should work.

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: I put let terrain because it is an example, really it is a variable that change because I am using react and redux and terrain is a state variable so depending on the state it has a value or other. And the code you wrote doesn't work for me.

Comment: Writting `[sel: string]: any;` inside TERR_CREATE works

Comment: "the code you wrote doesn't work for me".  I added playground links, you can see that the code does work.  If you're having a problem, post the specifics about what's not working.  Adding a string index to `TERR_CREATE` with `[sel: string]: any` widens `keyof TERR_CREATE` to `string`, which will allow typos like `terrain = "Planes"`.  If you prefer to limit `terrain` to a known set of string literals, then don't add that string index.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript infers that "terrain" is string, specify the type of "terrain" as keyof TERR_CREATE.

Or declare as const.

Comment: I am trying to declare it as const and as keyof TERR_CREATE , but it continues with that error because typescript continue considering it as string

Comment: let terrain: (keyof TERR_CREATE) = "Plains";
    let sel : (keyof TERR_CREATE) = terrain;
Did you try this? It should work, basically you have two variables of the same type.